# Angular 2 - Child componente of another child component doesn't load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I configured the routes, but the component does not render when the application is initialized. I need the `posts` component render within the `blog` component, since the blog already loads correctly.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { BlogModule } from './blog/blog.module';
import { CandidatosModule } from './candidatos/candidatos.module';
import { AboutModule } from './about/about.module';
import { NavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BlogModule,
    CandidatosModule,
    AboutModule,
    NavbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<!-- corpo da página -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.routing.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: BlogComponent},
    { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent},
    { path: 'candidatos', component: CandidatosComponent},
    { path: 'sobre', component: AboutComponent},
];
```

**blog.component.html:**

```
<div id="conteudo" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      hello, world!
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <!-- direita -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <app-aside></app-aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**blog.routing.module.ts:**

```
const blogRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: PostsComponent },
      { path: 'posts', component: PostsComponent },
      { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent },
      { path: 'estudos', component: EstudosComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

print demonstrating where to load the posts component:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTPbG.png)

Comment: Let's start with your app.module.ts

Comment: A plnkr would be helpful as you cannot provide all the contents of all files here , try to create a plnkr or provide app.module.ts and its app routing module file

Comment: @AakashUniyal I'm trying to put it on stackblitz

Comment: @vish213 i'm add te app.module.ts code to the question.

Comment: Can't see AppRoutingModule

Answer (score 0):

The user [Eduardo Vargas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/78981/eduardo-vargas), in [portuguese version](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297751/componente-filho-de-outro-componente-n%C3%A3o-carrega/297863#297863) of this forum, answered the question:

**app.routing.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/blog', pathMatch: 'full' }
    { path: 'candidatos', component: CandidatosComponent},
    { path: 'sobre', component: AboutComponent},
];
```